# Primefaces - Editable Panelgrid

Tags: primefaces

I have a primefaces datagrid (example see here: [PanelGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml)) that consists of two columns, namely keys and values. [image: Panelgrid with keys and values]

Now I would like to edit the values by clicking on a edit button, edit several values in the second column and save them afterwards by clicking on a save button.

I know that there is a control called Inplace ([Inplace](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inplace.xhtml)) but this allows to edit the values only consecutively. I'm very new to primefaces so I'm happy for every hint you can give me.

Comment: Not possible in the component. It is very generic.

Comment: Ok so do I have to implement my own JavaScript to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Most likely... in a combination of an input and output component on the client side and show/hide it based on some javascript/jquery. When you update/submit the inputs, you update the outputs as well (either via javascript/jquery or ajax update) (this is kind of what PF does with the editable datatable). Or use the rendered attribute of an input and an output component and update the full panelgrid

Comment: Hm, well then I'll have a try. Thanks much for the help dude!